# Ckeditor - Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-ckeditor

I am trying to figure out how to customize the Ckeditor text box in my form.  I have installed CKeditor locally and it works fine when I run it locally.  When I try to run it from the CDN, I can't figure out how to customize my textarea.  It will display fine using the CDN, but it's only the text area, no functions for the text area.  I've spent the last two days looking for an answer but nothing seems to work.  My HTML form looks like this:

```
<div class="spacer1">
  <label class="label6">Roster</label>
  <textarea class="bushes">
    {{ form.procedure }}
  </textarea>
```

When I run my app, it is just showing me the django-ckeditor-widget HTML in the textarea.  As shown below:

```
<div class="django-ckeditor-widget" data-field-id="id_procedure" style="display: inline-block;">
    <textarea cols="40" id="id_procedure" maxlength="2000" name="procedure" rows="10" required data-processed="0" data-config="{"skin": "moono-lisa", "toolbar_Basic": [["Source", "-", "Bold", "Italic"]], "toolbar_Full": [["Styles", "Format", "Bold", "Italic", "Underline", "Strike", "SpellChecker", "Undo", "Redo"], ["Link", "Unlink", "Anchor"], ["Image", "Flash", "Table", "HorizontalRule"], ["TextColor", "BGColor"], ["Smiley", "SpecialChar"], ["Source"]], "toolbar": "Full", "height": 291, "width": 835, "filebrowserWindowWidth": 940, "filebrowserWindowHeight": 725, "language": "en-us"}" data-external-plugin-resources="[]" data-id="id_procedure" data-type="ckeditortype">
```

If I try to display the form in my HTML as form.as_p, it works fine, when I try to customize this portion of my django form, it won't work.  I'm not a fan of the default form.as_p display, I need to be able to customize the look of the form.  I've also tried to do an {{ form.procedure|safe|escape }} but to no avail.  I am trying to run the CKEditor from the CDN as it seems to load faster than if it is running locally on my laptop.

I'm open to ideas on if there are other ways to run get Ckeditor to load faster locally if that's a possibility.  Or running it from the CDN is fine as well, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the toolbar when using the CDN or the Django template to work either.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: You can add your own classes in field in the form class you've created for the form for customization. Or, make your own textarea using only HTML. You just need to keep the `name` attribute of HTML element the same as the field name in the form class.

Comment: @Sachin Kukreja .  Thanks for taking the time to help.  Yes, I am able to now alter the form and set the box how I want.  The remaining question is the template tag in the HTML and the toolbar for the CKEditor on the form itself.  I added the link but the form is not presenting with a toolbar, just an empty text editor.  Where do I specify the options for the CDN version?  With the local version, I set the options in the settings.py file and that worked but it doesn't appear to work with the CDN version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I was able to determine that the {{ form.procedure }} reference inside of the text area is what was causing all of the HTML source code to appear in the textarea.  Ultimately I determined that I needed to revert back to the django-ckeditor program that I was using to get my desired configuration to work.  For future googlers, I was ultimately able to help myself troubleshooting by running the native HTML code outside of Django to try to troubleshoot what was going on.  I had some conflicting source libraries for Ckeditor and once I determined that the django template reference was causing me some grief as well, I was able to sort everything out.